# change marker icon on mouseover ( google maps V3 )

Tags: google-maps-api-3

```
var image = 'bullets/_st_zzzzzzl SSS.gif';

var bar1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng, 
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: "bar number 1"       
}); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(bar1, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,bar1);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(bar1, 'mouseout', function() {
        infowindow.close(map,bar1);
    });
```

Now when im on mouseover i want the icon to change to another image i got.
i tried some tips and some code but nothing works...
Appreciate ur help

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use `marker.setIcon()` function. The rest is almost the same as opening/closing infowindow in your code:

```
var icon1 = "imageA.png";
var icon2 = "imageB.png";

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: icon1,
    title: "some marker"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    marker.setIcon(icon2);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    marker.setIcon(icon1);
});
```

Note that besides using image paths in `setIcon()` function, you can also use `google.maps.MarkerImage` objects, which are very useful, especially if you want to use image sprites.

Comment: Could you please provide solution for sprite. I try to use `setIcon()` to change icon origin on mouseover and this not work

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});

// assuming you also want to hide the infowindow when user mouses-out
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    infowindow.close();
});
```